# Is there a standard .NET enum containing name for Location HTTP header?

Tags: c#, http-headers

`System.Net.HttpRequestHeader` enum contains a number of HTTP headers, but there's no `Location` header. Is there any system enum conatining this?

I am aware that I can just make a constant inside my application (that's what I did and it works fine) - I just wanted to be sure I did the best thing possible.

BTW, if it is not present in .NET libraries - does anyone know why? This header must be quite often used for RESTful services utilizing HTTP 201.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of `HttpRequestHeader` is:

> The HTTP headers that may be specified in a **client request**.

(Emphasis added).

`Location` isn't valid in a request, I believe, but only in a response. So we find [`HttpResponseHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpresponseheader.aspx):

> The HTTP headers that can be specified in a *server response*.

(Emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. Will accept when SO allows me to do it.

Comment: Better than just the link. Reversed my -1. :)

Comment: @StuartBlackler - yep, sorry for that - I suspected it was going to be a quick question/answer session, so I posted the link, then edited it (and was doing so when you first commented). A bit cheeky, perhaps :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpResponseHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpresponseheader.aspx)(not `HttpRequestHeader`) contains `HttpResponseHeader.Location` member.